# inserting input filed as an arry and its value to table

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am having a simple query that is creating trouble for me..
i need to insert my form containing basically 2 input field

```
<input type="text" name="slottiming[]" value="" ></input>
<input type="text" name="slottname[]" value=""></input>
```

.
.
.
..

Like the same i am creating 48 input fields (pairs) to store in 2 fields in my table

```
|id | Timing | Slotname
| 1 | 00:00  | 4
|   |        |
```

here is my controller ::

```
$slotname=$this->input->post('slotname');
        $slot=$this->input->post('slot');

            print_r($slotname);

        foreach($slotname as $key =>$slot)
        {
                $form_data=array(
                'slottime'=>$slotname,
                'seat' =>$key,
                'assocviva' => 'Cycle1'
                );
            $this->load->model('modelquery');
            $this->modelquery->common_add($table_name,$form_data);

        }
```

how to write the correct query to `insert into` common_add method as `$form_data` parameter arry with field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use a foreach here. Since they are pairs, you should use a for loop to sincronize the same result.

```
$this->load->model('modelquery');
$slotname = $this->input->post('slotname');
$slot     = $this->input->post('slot');

for ($i=0; $i < count($slotname); $i++){
 $form_data = array(
  'slottime' => $slotname[$i],
  'seat'     => $slot[$i],
  'assocviva'=> 'Cycle1'
 );
 $this->modelquery->common_add($table_name, $form_data);
}
```

**never put a model loading line inside a loop.**

Comment: yes but i would like to make little correction in your code.
'slottime' => $slotname[$i],
  'seat'     => $slot[$i],

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for the following answer?

function common_add($table_name, $form_data)

{

 $this->db->insert($table_name, $form_data); 

}

have a look at the database inserting documentation in http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, $slotname is the array you want to store?

One quick fix would be to serialize the array before you insert it to the DB and unserialize when you retrieve it from the DB.

```
$form_data=array(
    'slottime' => serialize($slotname),
    'seat' => $key,
    'assocviva' => 'Cycle1'
);
```

Then when you get it from the DB

```
$slotname = unserialize($row->slotname);
```

Comment: firstly thanks for the intrest, but i need to add without serializing. so that changes can be made from backend if needed..

Comment: Then I would recommend storing the items from the array in a separate table, with a field to reference which entry in the main table they belong to. Or make all 48 fields in the main table.